# Concat doesn't seem to work on a JSON obtained array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, concatenation

I'm having a some trouble with the concat function in javascript.  As far as I can tell, I'm using it correctly, but it's not successfully concatenating the array "value" from the JSON onto the array "currentAbilities":

```
$.each(ABILITIES, function(key,value) {
        if(key==raceName||(key==className&&(!isAcolyte)))
        {
            document.getElementById('abs').innerHTML = value[1];
            currentAbilities.concat(value);
        }
    })
```

The innerHTML setting line shows that the array "value" does exist.  Any idea why I'm failing to concat?  Value of course comes from a JSON, could that have anything to do with it?  I'm afraid I only recently became familiar with $.each and JSON usage and may be doing it wrong.

Comment: Would it not be the same, in this instance, as `currentAbilities += value;` ?

Comment: JSON tends not to return arrays, but objects. Try iterating through the object and storing its values in an array, and then concatenating to it.

Comment: This is the format of abilities.  
ABILITIES = {"race1":["Ab1"],"race2":["Ab2"],"class1":["Ab3","Ab4"],"class2":["Ab4","Ab5"],"class3":["Ab6","Ab4"]};
If the JSON is returning an object, then sure, I can iterate through it, in fact, then I wouldn't use concat at all, I just wanted to avoid that.

Comment: @arxanas: JSON doesn't return anything except a string of that which it was built to represent. This can include array structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the JSON has been parsed, you need to keep a reference to the new Array created by `concat()` because the `.concat()` method does not modify the original...

```
currentAbilities = currentAbilities.concat(value);
```

---

Or just use `.push` with `.apply` if you want to modify the `currentAbilities` array...

```
currentAbilities.push.apply(currentAbilities, value)
```

---

Also, make sure your `raceName` and `className` variables are what you expect.

Comment: This looks like it may be problem, let me give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, that did it, I missed the currentAbilities = currentAbilities.concat(value); syntax, now I feel silly.